# What are "other storyboard compiler flags" in Xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, ibtool

I'm maintaining an interesting application (target iOS6). After fixing all existing compiler warnings and lots of other stuff found by static code analyzers, I'm running short of warnings to fix. Already added **-Wall** and **-Werror**, not very keen to add the others yet.

Then I found something interesting, which so far seems to be completely unknown by google or StackOverflow!

Xcode5 project "Build Settings" have a subsection called **"Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler - Options"**. Four cases are pretty understandable:

- Flatten Compiled Storyboard Files (YES)
- Show Errors (YES)
- Show Notices (YES)
- Show Warnigns (YES)

**Question**: what can I put into the ***"Other Storyboard Compiler Flags"***? Where can I find more info?

Comment: I am also very interested in this and even just filed a Radar that might be already solvable using these (apparently undocumented?) flags. Very curious to find out more about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Other Storyboard Compiler Flags` you can pass command line arguments to `ibtool`. The list of flags are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html). I assume you would like to have Xcode treat interface builder warnings as errors. Seems that such an argument is not available as of Xcode 7.3.

There is another section under "Build Settings" titled **Interface Builder XIB Compiler** that also targets `ibtool` and you can pass the same options to. Xcode 7.3 passes the flags: `--warnings --errors --notices` among others by default. `ibtool` will fail with an error if you pass an argument that it does not recognize.